# Whats the best way to create a NavigationTitle in Neos?

Tags: fusion, neoscms

Whats the best way to have a Field "Navigation Title" in Neos?

I'd like to get a field to "overwrite" PageTitle with a shorter Version used in the Navigation-Menu.

*Im loooking for the same function Typo3 offers with their field "navigation title".*

**Example:**
I want the long Title in `<title>` etc, but i prefer a short-title in the navigation menu.

`Page Title: "Pretty long and nice Page-Title about the Page Communication"
Navigation Title: "Communication"`

Answer (score 1):

I'd add it as a property to your page type (or to `Neos.Neos:Document`). The `MenuImplementation` of the default Fusion `Menu` object uses the "label" of the page type, so you can just set it so it uses your custom navigationTitle property.
So you'd have this:

```
'Neos.Neos:Document':
  label: "${String.cropAtWord(String.trim(String.stripTags(String.pregReplace(q(node).property('navigationTitle') || q(node).property('title') ... [all the rest of the default label]"
```

The default label can be seen in the `NodeTypes.yaml` file under `./Packages/Application/Neos.Neos/Configuration`, so you can copy it from there and add your navigationTitle to it.

[edit: the line-break after "label:" is added by StackOverflow - there shouldn't actually be one in your YAML.]

Answer (score 0):

There is the [Neos.Seo package](https://github.com/neos/neos-seo) which adds this functionality and further SEO features like Meta tags, Sitemap, Social tags, Structured data. The additional field added to the document properties is named `titleOverride`.

If you use this package you can just use the included fusion prototype to handle the title tag:

```
prototype(Neos.Neos:Page) {
  head {
    titleTag >
    titleTag = Neos.Seo:TitleTag
  }
}
```